# LUKS full disk encryption fails from boot but live-CD is able to unlock partition - Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, kubuntu, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

When trying to boot with Kubuntu I can't get the root to decrypt. That is an old installation that worked for months. I can't remember what was updated before it stopped working.
I've verified that it is not due to keyboard layout, because
from initramfs using `echo -n "test1" | cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt` it is also not working.
Using that command from Live-CD or dolphin works so there it decrypts.

After trying different things like chroot and creating a new initramfs and grub-update, apt update and reinstalling things like cryptsetup and others I gave up.

I ordered a new nvme drive which I put into the PC. After installing Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with encrypted harddrive on the newly installed device I get the same error message as before when trying to unlock the newly installed Kubuntu after the first reboot.

I'm at a loss. Could it be hardware-specific? I Use an AMD Ryzen 5 5600X and MSI B550-A PRO.

edit: additional info from the cryptsetup command rin under initramfs:

```
# cryptsetup 2.4.3 processing "cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt --debug --verbose"
# Running command open.
# Locking memory.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating context for crypt device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/nvme0n1p3 with direct-io.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Trying to load any crypt type from device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Crypto backend (OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 [default]) initialized in cryptsetup library version 2.4.3.
# Detected kernel Linux 5.15.0-43-generic x86_64.
# Loading LUKS2 header (repair disabled).
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_259:3
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock taken.
# Trying to read primary LUKS2 header at offset 0x0.
# Opening locked device /dev/nvme0n1p3
# Verifying locked device handle (bdev)
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:6369a9195ce5cecf8565547247efdee1d348591e7fda341591d1e67d8bdc24f9 (on-disk)
# Checksum:6369a9195ce5cecf8565547247efdee1d348591e7fda341591d1e67d8bdc24f9 (in-memory)
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x4000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme0n1p3
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:a0619dc4d56b8426ba9a3ad7da84b62cf99295b7c0d88a40eba1f9c588c14731 (on-disk)
# Checksum:a0619dc4d56b8426ba9a3ad7da84b62cf99295b7c0d88a40eba1f9c588c14731 (in-memory)
# Device size 997874204672, offset 16777216.
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock released.
# PBKDF argon2id, time_ms 2000 (iterations 0), max_memory_kb 1048576, parallel_threads 4.
# Activating volume nvme0n1p3_crypt using token (any type) -1.
# dm version   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Detected dm-ioctl version 4.45.0.
# Detected dm-crypt version 1.23.0.
# Device-mapper backend running with UDEV support enabled.
# dm status nvme0n1p3_crypt  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
No usable token is available.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
# Activating volume nvme0n1p3_crypt [keyslot -1] using passphrase.
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm status nvme0n1p3_crypt  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Keyslot 0 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Keyslot 1 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 0.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x8000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_259:3
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme0n1p3
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 0, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 1.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x47000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_259:3
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme0n1p3
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 1, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
# Activating volume nvme0n1p3_crypt [keyslot -1] using passphrase.
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm status nvme0n1p3_crypt  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Keyslot 0 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Keyslot 1 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 0.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x8000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_259:3
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme0n1p3
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 0, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 1.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x47000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_259:3
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme0n1p3
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 1, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
# Activating volume nvme0n1p3_crypt [keyslot -1] using passphrase.
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm status nvme0n1p3_crypt  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Keyslot 0 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Keyslot 1 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 0.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x8000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_259:3
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme0n1p3
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 0, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 1.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x47000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_259:3
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/nvme0n1p3
# Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 1, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
# Releasing crypt device /dev/nvme0n1p3 context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Closing read only fd for /dev/nvme0n1p3.
# Unlocking memory.
Command failed with code -2 (no permission or bad passphrase).
```

output from cat /proc/modules

```
nls_iso8859_1 16384 1 - Live 0xffffffffc0146000
uas 28672 0 - Live 0xffffffffc018e000
usb_storage 77824 2 uas, Live 0xffffffffc01b6000
dm_crypt 53248 0 - Live 0xffffffffc01a8000
hid_generic 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0210000
iommu_v2 24576 0 - Live 0xffffffffc03ab000
gpu_sched 45056 0 - Live 0xffffffffc02b3000
i2c_algo_bit 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0297000
drm_ttm_helper 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0292000
ttm 86016 1 drm_ttm_helper, Live 0xffffffffc027c000
usbhid 65536 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0197000
drm_kms_helper 307200 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0478000
hid 147456 2 hid_generic,usbhid, Live 0xffffffffc0169000
syscopyarea 16384 1 drm_kms_helper, Live 0xffffffffc0162000
sysfillrect 20480 1 drm_kms_helper, Live 0xffffffffc015a000
sysimgblt 16384 1 drm_kms_helper, Live 0xffffffffc0153000
fb_sys_fops 16384 1 drm_kms_helper, Live 0xffffffffc014c000
cec 61440 1 drm_kms_helper, Live 0xffffffffc0136000
crct10dif_pclmul 16384 1 - Live 0xffffffffc020b000
crc32_pclmul 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc026d000
ghash_clmulni_intel 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc012e000
rc_core 65536 1 cec, Live 0xffffffffc08cb000
aesni_intel 376832 0 - Live 0xffffffffc040d000
crypto_simd 16384 1 aesni_intel, Live 0xffffffffc0206000
cryptd 24576 2 ghash_clmulni_intel,crypto_simd, Live 0xffffffffc0275000
r8169 98304 0 - Live 0xffffffffc03e3000
drm 606208 4 gpu_sched,drm_ttm_helper,ttm,drm_kms_helper, Live 0xffffffffc02f4000
nvme 45056 0 - Live 0xffffffffc02e1000
i2c_piix4 28672 0 - Live 0xffffffffc02d5000
ahci 45056 0 - Live 0xffffffffc02c1000
gpio_amdpt 20480 0 - Live 0xffffffffc02ad000
xhci_pci 24576 0 - Live 0xffffffffc02a2000
nvme_core 126976 1 nvme, Live 0xffffffffc0248000
realtek 32768 0 - Live 0xffffffffc023b000
libahci 45056 1 ahci, Live 0xffffffffc022a000
xhci_pci_renesas 20480 1 xhci_pci, Live 0xffffffffc0222000
wmi 32768 0 - Live 0xffffffffc01f8000
gpio_generic 20480 1 gpio_amdpt, Live 0xffffffffc0128000
```

Comment: The fact that you can open the LUKs partition from a Live USB tells me it is not hardware (the SSD or the CPU) specific. What is the exact error you get? [Add the information to your qeustion](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1454265/edit). Can you try booting from the previous kernel?

Comment: You are right. It must be the difference between the "normal environment" after boot and the one during startup. So I added the output from cryptsetup and the modules to my question.
But what still puzzles me is that this happens with a fresh install, aren't there more people affected if it is not some weird  hardware dependent combination for me.

Comment: and yes, the addition to my question was made with trying  an older kernel. Did not work as seen in the output.

Comment: Found a bug report, this is maybe my problem too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1986623

Comment: Unfortunately the older kernel does not work. 
My test from above (see output) was witjh the kernel 5.15.0-43 mentioned by the bug comment you linked to. He mentioned that this kernel worked for him. That makes me think it is not the kernel that is causing the bug.